# show line numbers in TeXstudio 2.10.8

Tags: texstudio

I searched with Google, but could not find how to show line numbers in TeXstudio 2.10.8.
I thus request this community's help.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Step by step:

- Options
- Configure TeXstudio
- Enable advanced options for the editor (in the lower left "Show Advanced Options")
- Use Advanced editor options ("Adv. Editor" on the left)
- Activate line numbers (select "All lines and numbers" in drop down menu "Show line numbers")

Comment: Thank you. I was unable to find the solution when I googled it.

Comment: This still haunts me. The developers are utterly insane to think showing line numbers is an advanced use which should be hidden 4 option layers deep.

Comment: @Anti Earth I agree. I don't know why latex editors are all so weird. Error messages are referenced by line number.

Comment: The option is in the `Editor` on the left, not `Adv. Editor`