# Show line number in Texstudio2.12.22 (Activate line numbers not found in configure)

Tags: texstudio

Hi I just installed my `TeXstudio 2.12.22` and want it to show the line number of my files. I know that this seems like a duplicate question, and the solution is here:[solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/296716/213285). But I tried these steps:

- Open texstudio configure.
- Enable advance options.
- Choose"Adv. Editor" on the left.
- Do not find the "Show line numbers" option.

Here is a screenshot of my configure page. As you can see, there is no such option in the `Appearance` section. I am not sure what causes this. Could you help me? Thank you very much.

[image: Configure]

Comment: Choose "Editor", other than "Adv. Editor", on the left, then you can find the "Show Line Numbers" option.

Comment: (alternative solution) Right above "advance options" check box, there is a "(option filter)" box. Type in "line numbers" to that box, and you are directed to the desired option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to muzimuzhi, problem solved.

It seems like `Texstudio 2.12` changes the `show line number` option from `Adv. Editor` to `Editor`. So what you need to do is:

- Open texstudio configure.
- Enable advance options.
- Choose"Editor" on the left.
- Find "Show line numbers" and change it to be "All line numbers".

Then you could see the line number in your editor. Or you could just search "line number" in the `option filter` box above the `Show advance options` option.